# Depth data always nil

Tags: ios, swift, camera

I am trying to capture photos with depth data using the back camera I followed the example on apple website [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/capturing_photos_with_depth) but the depth data is always nil. I tried this solution on multiple ios devices but I keep getting nil

my code:

```
func setupCamare(){
    
    // Select a depth-capable capture device.
    guard let videoDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualCamera,
        for: .video, position: .back)
        else { fatalError("No dual camera.") }
    
    guard let videoDeviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoDevice),
        self.captureSession.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput)
        else { fatalError("Can't add video input.") }
    
    
    guard self.captureSession.canAddOutput(photoOutput)
        else { fatalError("Can't add photo output.") }

    self.captureSession.beginConfiguration()
    self.captureSession.addInput(videoDeviceInput)
    
    // Set up photo output for depth data capture.
    photoOutput.isHighResolutionCaptureEnabled = true
    
    print(photoOutput.isDepthDataDeliverySupported)
    photoOutput.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled = photoOutput.isDepthDataDeliverySupported

    self.captureSession.addOutput(photoOutput)
    self.captureSession.sessionPreset = .photo
    self.captureSession.commitConfiguration()
            
    videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    
    videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
    view.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)
    
    captureSession.startRunning()
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.button)
}


@IBAction func takePhoto(_ sender:UIButton){
    let photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecType.jpeg])
    photoSettings.isDepthDataFiltered = photoOutput.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled;
    
    photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: self)
}
```